# Send email from address with laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I have configured my mail.php config file to send emails using the gmail account.
Everything looks great, but when I try to send email from another account (not the address used in the mail.php config file) I get an email from the address set on the configuration file.

```
Mail::send('emails.contact_mail', array(
            'email' => $fromEmail,
            'name' => $user,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'message' => $message_content,
                ), function($message)use ($fromEmail,$user,$subject) {

                    $message->to('s111@gmail.com');
                    $message->from('test@gmail.com', $user);
                    $message->subject($subject);

                });
```

It seems like the `$message->from` doesn't work. I get on the `s111@gmail.com` an email from the address set in `mail.php` file and not from `test@gmail.com`.
Is there any solution? How to change the `from` address?

Answer (score 2):

You will still use the SMTP servers set in your config file. Setting another 'from' header is theoretically possible, but the GMail SMTP will ignore it unless you set an address that has been added to your Google account.

Solution: either don't use another 'from' address, or add that address to your Google account.

Comment: Or use a SMTP server that'll accept arbitrary `from` headers.

Comment: He could do that, but most spam filters will catch those mails.

Comment: I use Mandrill and as long as I'm sending for one of my domains with valid SPF/DKIM it doesn't have to be an extant address (i.e. `noreply@example.com` works fine).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you can try:

```
$message->replyTo('test@gmail.com', $user);
```

And to my understanding, the "From: " header in emails is what should determine what it will display as the sender. This may work for changing the "From" header:

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('From', 'Your Name <test@gmail.com>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best solution for this question.
We can figure out this as follows:
$message->from('sender@email.com', 'sender_name');
And also we should remove the following code block in config/mail.php.

```
'from' => [
 'address' => 'sender@email.com',
 'name' => 'sender_name',
],
```

of course, this will be working on Laravel Framework.